# e2fsck miserably aborts: memory allocation failed on 64 bit OS and scratch directory

Tags: linux, partition, data-recovery, ext4, fsck

After an unsuccessful Virtualbox VDI drive resize following the [instructions here](http://trivialproof.blogspot.com/2011/01/resizing-virtualbox-virtual-hard-disk.html#expand_partition_on_new_vdi), the primary ext4 partition became of unknown type.

I fixed this with testdisk and then boot-repair, which made it be recognized as ext4 but not boot. Instead, it is reported as having 95% free space while this figure should be of 5% instead (I have the pastebins of boot-repair [before](http://paste.ubuntu.com/910638/) and [after](http://paste.ubuntu.com/910655/)).

I can mount the partition with backup superblocks using `sudo mount -o sb=131072 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1`, but there is only a lost+found folder inside (using other superblocks doesn't change what is visible).

Therefore, as per [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/) and [these](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/), I tried to run `sudo e2fsck -y -b 32768 /dev/sdb1` on it from within another Ubuntu 11.10 OS 64 bits with 4 GB or RAM and plenty of disk space, but it eats up all the RAM, part of the swap, and miserably aborts after around 30s saying:

```
Error storing directory block information (inode=115343515, block=0, num=108120142): Memory allocation failed
e2fsck: aborted
```

I tried specifying a scratch directory as per the [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/5/e2fsck.conf/) and answers suggested [here](http://www.linux-archive.org/ext3-users/103464-2gb-memory-limit-running-fsck-6tb-device.html), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9218/running-out-of-memory-running-fsck-on-large-filesystems),[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/288409/e2fsck-on-large-filesystem-fails-with-error-memory-allocation-failed#_=_), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/201554/e2fsck-aborts-memory-allocation-failed), and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/288409/e2fsck-on-large-filesystem-fails-with-error-memory-allocation-failed), but nothing has helped thus far overcome the out of memory error.

Do you know of any alternative tool to fsck?

I am desperate not to be able to proceed with the file system repair just because of a memory issue... Given the pace at which it is eating up memory, I doubt having more would help at all.